# Weird behaviour: Apache PHP Windows with FSockopen

Tags: php, windows, apache, fsockopen

Consider this simple code:

```
 <?php
   error_reporting(E_ALL);
   //error_reporting(E_STRICT);
   date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Calcutta');
   $smtp_server = fsockopen("onelocalserver.com", 25, $errno, $errstr, 120);
   if(!$smtp_server)
     {
  // We have an error, do something
  echo " Error found! <br>$errno <br>$errstr";
  exit;
     }
  ?>
```

On Windows XP + php5.3.8 + apache 2.2, i get an error: 
Warning: fsockopen(): unable to connect to onelocalserver.com:25 (No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. )

However, on the same system where Apache and PHP are installed, if i run php from the command prompt ex: c:\php\php.exe filename.php (where above code is in the filename), then i don't get the error!

The server onelocalserver.com is listening on port 25 : there is an SMTP server running there.

Any ideas? This is really bizzare

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you have any firewall software installed on the machine? Sounds to me like `php.exe` is allowed to make outgoing connections, and `httpd.exe` is not. Try disabling your firewall software temporarily, and if it then works, add `httpd.exe` to it's exceptions list. `the target machine actively refused it` suggests that a TCP `RST` packet is being received in response to the `SYN`, so get [Wireshark](http://wireshark.org/) out and confirm if this is the case.

Comment: Thanks for the tip on Wireshark. I ran it and when i used the command line interface on php, i see that the request went through. But when i executed the file over the browser, wireshark didn't even register any entries for the IP address that i used with fsockopen! I replaced the hostname with the correct IP address in the fsockopen command! Weird! The IT folks claim that no firewall is running. I saw a microsoft firewall service running, stopped it as well, with the same result! Any ideas, please?

Comment: If you see nothing at all in WS when trying it through Apache, there is definitely some kind of packet filter somewhere blocking the packets before they are allowed to pass to the network. The Windows firewall server has no functionality (AFAIK) for filtering outbound traffic, that falls into the domain of annoying pieces of software like Norton and McAfee - these are the usual suspects, have a good hard look for any trace of either on the system.

Answer (score 0):

After several tries with different IP addresses, i realised that the only problem was with fsockopen on port 25. It works well with command line interface but didn't work through the web browser. PHP was earlier installed in windows as CGI. I thought i will see if it still doesn't work when set up as an Apache handler and it works! http://www.php.net/manual/en/install.windows.apache2.php .

Hope this helps someone!